# What does the radius of Fermi-Surface or the wavevector says about the occupied electronic states?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, molecules, fermi-energy

I have the following task:

Consider a simple cubic structure with a lattice constant of 0.3 nm and one atom per unit cell; the
macroscopic crystal has a size of 1 cm³. Assume that each atom contributes one valence electron.

I already calculatet the largest k-vector within the first Brillouin zone and the fermi wavevector k_f. Now I have to answer if all occupied electronic states within the first Brillouin zone are at Fermi-Temperatur?

My answer would be yes, because the fermi wavevector is smaller than the largest k-vector within the first Brillouin zone and so the Fermi-Surface is fully in the 1st Zone. Is my assumption right or how do I answer this question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.